# Running same query with different where clause for showing in different tabs on page

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of companies like this

```
+-------+---------+------+---------------+
| Title | Address | City | CompanyTypeId |
+-------+---------+------+---------------+
| A     | Address | City |             1 |
| B     | Address | City |             2 |
| C     | Address | City |             2 |
| D     | Address | City |             3 |
| E     | Address | City |             2 |
| F     | Address | City |             2 |
| G     | Address | City |             4 |
| H     | Address | City |             5 |
| I     | Address | City |             2 |
| J     | Address | City |             6 |
| K     | Address | City |             7 |
| L     | Address | City |             2 |
+-------+---------+------+---------------+
```

I am tasked with seperating them according to their types and list them under *seperate* tabs on our page.

So basically I need to show a list of same query with changing where conditions. 
I set the bootstrap tabs and was wondering if it was possible parameterize the variable and change it with tab changes on page. I guess I'll have to use AJAX  but not sure if it's the right choice either.

And of course, if it's possible how can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this question yourself? If yes, can you add the code from your attempt?

Comment: you could do it with a table with search filters above it

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what to use. I'm not experienced enough in such a situation to try solving this myself without a little push at start :)

Comment: Sadly no, I can't use filters. Seperate tabs. Boss orders.